# How to find what is a character

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I have a string `cb` (from an input I do not control):

```
foo     

    bar
```

If I transform this string into a list:

```
>>> print(cb.splitlines())
['foo \t', '', '    bar']
```

I need the `\t`, but not the empty string nor the leading (and potentially trailing) spaces. So I trim a little:

```
cb_formatted = list(filter(None, cb.splitlines()))
for l in cb_formatted:
    l = l.strip()
```

But then:

```
>>> print(cb_formatted)
['foo \t', '    bar']
```

The leading spaces are still here! So maybe those aren't spaces... But what are they?

So I do this:

```
    cb_formatted = list(filter(None, cb.splitlines()))
    print(cb_formatted)
    for l in cb_formatted:
        l = l.strip()
        for c in l:
            print(c + "-" + ord(c))
```

But then:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\foobar.py", line 61, in <module>
    print(c + "-" + ord(c))
TypeError: must be str, not int
```

I tried `ord(str(c))` with no more luck.

How can I find what are those characters ?

And, optionnally, is there a better method than `strip()` to trim them?

Comment: can you please say what is your expected output finally ?

Comment: You can't add a number to a string, but `c + "-" + ord(c)` attempts to do exactly that. Try `c + "-" + str(ord(c))` instead.

Comment: The input you shared has no weird chars inside, just plain tab and spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't concatenate string and integer objects. `ord(c)` returns a integer (number).
Try:

```
print(c + "-" + str(ord(c)))
```

Also, `strip` takes a argument which is a string defining all the characters that should be trimmed away: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip

Answer (score 2):

The original problem stems from this approach:

```
cb_formatted = list(filter(None, cb.splitlines()))
for l in cb_formatted:
    l = l.strip()
```

You're expecting assigning to `l` to modify the list, but it won't. It just assigns to a variable l which has also had assigned to it the string from the list, as strings *cannot* be mutated. Also, `.strip()` will also strip a tab character. I think this should produce your desired behaviour:

```
cb_formatted = [line.strip(" ") for line in filter(None, cb.splitlines())]
```

Answer (score 1):

In the lines

```
for l in cb_formatted:
    l = l.strip()
```

you set the name of the stripped element to the name you use for the elements in the loop (`l`). So on each iteration, your last stripped item will be lost and after the loop `l` will contain the last stripped item.
Furthermore you did not change the list itself at all.

For the other error, see @johk95 's answer

Answer (score 0):

When you strip the elements of the list, you're creating new strings, but not changing the list.

To get the result you want, use this:

```
cb_formatted = [ l.strip(' ') for l in cb.splitlines() if l ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish your output by using `str.strip` for each element in your list, and storing the resultant new string. Assuming you have a list of lines:

```
>>> lines = ['foo \t', '', '    bar']
>>> [s.strip(' ') for s in lines if s]
['foo \t', 'bar']
```